# Eager loading for reference

Tags: hl7-fhir

I wonder if it is possible to load reference data in the first call. In my case I want to load the patient reference in the Encounter Resource. As I know I always need the patient data I want to avoid to to do an additional call to get the patient data.

The server is HAPI FHIR and the client firely .Net API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Your request will have to be a search, that way you can include any referenced resources.

On REST level it looks like this:

```
GET <hapi_server>/Encounter?_include=patient
```

Add any filters you have. For example if you have a specific encounter you would add `&_id=<technical_id>`.

With the FhirClient from the .Net api, the code looks like this:

```
    var c = new FhirClient("<hapi_server");

    var q = new SearchParams().Include("Encounter:patient");
    q.Add("_id", "<technical_id>");

    var result = c.Search<Encounter>(q);
```